# ArcGIS Pro geocoding problem - unexplained error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, geocoding

I have the following addresses (csv format) to be geocoded for approximately 600 addresses.

| Brand | Address | Suburb | Postcode | Combined Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyv | 123 | abc | 6000 | 123 abc 6000 |

I tried to geocode them from add data-> geocode table but I have been getting an unexplained error. I have tried to geocode from both the multiple fields and single field method and neither has worked. I have the latest version as I only downloaded yesterday.

What can I do to fix it?

[image: Here's the summary and error].

Comment: Have you tried any of the other geocode options (i.e. Geocode Addresses)?

Comment: Yes just tried that and it works. Thank you!